# Swift Mysql Update statement not working

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am just trying to run a simple Update Query on my sqlite database, but the code is not actually updating the value in the DB and it's not throwing an error indicating a failure.  Below is the function I am running:

```
func updateItem(nameParam: String, priceParam: String) {
    print("UpdateItem() is running like a dream")
    var db: OpaquePointer?

    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("ItemsDatabase.sqlite")

    //opening the database
    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }

    //creating table
    if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, itemName TEXT, itemPrice INTEGER)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
    }


    //creating a statement
    var stmt: OpaquePointer?

    //the insert query
    let queryString = "UPDATE Items SET itemPrice = ? WHERE itemName = ?"

    //preparing the query
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //binding the parameters
    if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, priceParam, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, (nameParam as! NSString).intValue) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //executing the query to insert values
    if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure inserting item: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //displaying a success message
    print("Item successfully edited in the database")
}
```

I have tested the out put multiple times and the parameters are getting passed to the function as expected, and the query shows exactly what is expected and seems to be proper syntax.  I am unable to figure out what is causing the code to not actually update the table, or fail.

Comment: Is `priceParam` a text? I think you have functions in wrong order.

Comment: @Nomeaning25 the `priceParam` and `nameParam` variables are used in a different order than they are set as parameters for the function.  However `priceParam` is the first value that should be used in the query to be set as the value of `itemPrice` in the first bind statement

Comment: You forgot `sqlite3_finalize()` and `sqlite3_close()` in many places. Anyway, check [sqlite3_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html), and show an example of the row that you think should be updated.